# having trouble with embedding youtube video on jquery mobile site when viewed on android

Tags: android, mobile, jquery-mobile, youtube

well, the trouble is actually when trying to navigate through the menu to different pages (page id). first it asks to "tap here to activate plugin" but thats not the problam.
after activating the plugin, the video seems to stay on the screen while navigating to different pages.
tested it on gallaxy s2. (it works great on iphone 4 ios5)
would appreciate any help..
here is the link, sorry if you dont understand the language :
http://einatmaor.co.il/mobile

here is the code:

```
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
          <div data-theme="d" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <span class="ui-title">
             <img style="width: 100%; " src="images/logo.png" />
            </span>

            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page1" data-theme="a" data-icon="" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">
                           בית
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page2" data-theme="a" data-icon="" data-transition="slide">
                            אודות
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page3" data-theme="a" data-icon="" data-transition="slide">
                            שרותים
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page4" data-theme="a" data-icon="" data-transition="slide" >
                             צור קשר 
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="margin:0 auto;padding:5px;text-align:center;padding-top:25px;">
       <iframe width="300" height="169" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/F6P9rkh96jk?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>        
 <!-- about -->
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-theme="d" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <span class="ui-title">
             <img style="width: 100%;" src="images/logo.png" />
            </span>

            <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page1" data-theme="a" data-icon="" data-transition="slide" >
                           בית
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page2" data-theme="a" data-icon="" data-transition="slide" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">
                            אודות
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page3" data-theme="a" data-icon="" data-transition="slide">
                            שרותים
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page4" data-theme="a" data-icon="" data-transition="slide" >
                             צור קשר 
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
...and so on...
```

Comment: Were you able to ge this to work?